# XHTML, PHP, MySQL, IE and mdash character

Tags: php, mysql, html, internet-explorer, character-encoding

I have a problem with mdash character (—, or Alt+0151).

Thing is I have a page with dtd like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I also have a form (shortened version):

```
<form name="dep_new" action="whatever.php" method="post">
    <input class="mandatory" id="dname" type="text" name="dname" value="<?php echo $department->name; ?>"/>
</form>
```

It is working with PHP 5.2 and MySQL 5.1 to store value of that input.

Now, when I work with any other browse but IE and input an mdash character into this field (by typing it Alt+0151) I get a proper long dash. It saves and retrieves from database with no problem.

However when I try to save it using IE9 I get the following:

Typing: Test—Test

After save and refresh: Test—Test

In other browsers I see: Test�Test

Becasue this is a departmnet name it is being displayed on another page and the results I get are : 
In IE: TestTest
Other browsers: Test[a thing I cant post here - a square with 00 and 97 in it]Test

This square thing looks like this:

```
----
|00|
|97|
----
```

However if I do the same in say FF or Chrome, it displays fine in IE page as well while in IE input it shows:

> Testâ€”Test

Any attempt to encode/decode fails. 
However if I change dtd to:

> `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN>`

It all works fine in all browsers...

Any thoughts?

Comment: What character encoding data are you supplying via meta and the content-type header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Em-dash in standard [Ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) table or [ISO 8859-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) character set, it is available in [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) charset as 0x97 but this is a windows only standard. It is also available as unicode character U+2014 so you'd better use UTF-8 encoding for your pages if you want to safely use em-dash. add this to your `<head>`:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Comment: Ha! Thanks a lot. I was sure I checked that before, but apparently I must have missed it somehow... we have a pretty messed up code here we are trying to fix and apparently they are using some ifs to either load utf-8 or 8859-1. When I force it to load utf-8 it finally works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a call to [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) when you echo out the name:

```
<input class="mandatory" id="dname" type="text" name="dname"
       value="<?php echo htmlentities($department->name) ?>"/>
```

Comment: Sorry but it did not help. No change in behaviour whatsoever.